# How to correctly design spawning of GameObjects in giant world?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, mmo

I'm designing some kind of MMO strategy game with thousands of players. Since the game will not have frequent operations, i think it will not have scalability issues using Unity HLAPI. Using HLAPI, every GameObject with NetworkIdentity is spawned in each client. Since different players should not necessary be aware of each GameObject, how can I control which GameObjects are spawned on each player?

For example, suppose there is a giant map, and a discrete coordinate system. On each pair (x,y) there is a player Game Object. The server should be aware of each of them, but clients don't care about players far away from them. So I think the client performance will be affected if I spawn every GameObject on every client.